# PineScript - required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character ' '

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

New to Pinescript. I got this error, anyone knows what it means?

Script:

18- var g_filter = "Filter Settings"

19- ema filter = input(title="EMA Filter", type=input.integer, defval=0, group=g_filter, tooltip="EMA length to filter trades")

20- i_startTime = input(title="Start Date Filter", defval=timestamp("01 Jan 2000 13:00 +0000"), type=input.time,group= g_filter, tooltip="Date & Time - Start")

21- i_endTime = input(title="End Date Filter". defavl=timestamp("1 Jan 2020 19:30 +0000"), type=input.time, group=g_filter, tooltip="Date & Time - End")

Error:

line 21: required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character ' '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a **point** that you are not seeing after "End Date Filter"

replace point, with a comma

```
21- i_endTime = input(title="End Date Filter", defavl=timestamp("1 Jan 2020 19:30 +0000"), type=input.time, group=g_filter, tooltip="Date & Time - End")
```

Comment: Worked!, sometimes one small thing ruins everything...